# Android getComponentName() search

Tags: android

пишу свое приложение по статья, и в одной статье используется метод getComponentName() для добавления поиска в меню, но у меня Android Studio не видит этот метод. Как можно решить? Может это из-за того что я использую fragment, а не activity?

**Код:**

```
public class CityFragment extends Fragment{
private RecyclerView recyclerViewCity;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private SearchView searchView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_select_city, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Выбор города");
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Получение списка городов...");
    progressDialog.show();

    recyclerViewCity = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCity);
    recyclerViewCity.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewCity.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Call<Cities> call = service.getCities();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Cities>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Cities> call, Response<Cities> response) {

            adapter = new CityAdapter(response.body().getCities(),getActivity());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            recyclerViewCity.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Cities> call, Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.city_search,menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getC()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

}
```

}

Comment: Если вы хотите вызвать метод активности из фрагмента, есть два способа: `((MyActivity) getActivity()).function();` и правильный (через интерфейс)

Comment: попробуйте в одном из активити вызвать этот метод. Если он вызовется - значит это потому что вы во фрагменте работает. В таком случае, вам нужно воспользоваться советом № 1))

Comment: В activity этот метод виден